# Spark/Scala serialization of list. Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization

The issue is with Spark Dataset and serialization of a list of Ints. Scala version is 2.10.4 and Spark version is 1.6.

This is similar to other questions but I can't get it to work based on those responses. I've simplified the code down in order to just show the problem.

I have a case class:

```
case class FlightExt(callsign: Option[String], serials: List[Int])
```

And my main method is like this:

```
    val (ctx, sctx) = SparkUtil.createContext() // just a helper function to build context
    val flightsDataFrame = separateFlightsMock(sctx) // reads data from Parquet file

    import sctx.implicits._
    flightsDataFrame.as[FlightExt]
      .map(flight => flight.callsign)
      .show()
```

I get the following error:

```
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$PackageClassSymbol
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$PackageClassSymbol, value: package scala)
    - field (class: scala.reflect.internal.Types$ThisType, name: sym, type: class scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol)
    - object (class scala.reflect.internal.Types$UniqueThisType, scala.type)
    - field (class: scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef, name: pre, type: class scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type)
    - object (class scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef$$anon$6, scala.Int)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$5, name: elementType$2, type: class scala.reflect.api.Types$TypeApi)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$5, <function1>)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.MapObjects, name: function, type: interface scala.Function1)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.MapObjects, mapobjects(<function1>,cast(serials#7 as array<int>),IntegerType))
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Invoke, name: targetObject, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Invoke, invoke(mapobjects(<function1>,cast(serials#7 as array<int>),IntegerType),array,ObjectType(class [Ljava.lang.Object;)))
    - writeObject data (class: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon)
    - object (class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon, List(invoke(mapobjects(<function1>,cast(serials#7 as array<int>),IntegerType),array,ObjectType(class [Ljava.lang.Object;))))
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.StaticInvoke, name: arguments, type: interface scala.collection.Seq)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.StaticInvoke, staticinvoke(class scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$,ObjectType(interface scala.collection.Seq),make,invoke(mapobjects(<function1>,cast(serials#7 as array<int>),IntegerType),array,ObjectType(class [Ljava.lang.Object;)),true))
    - writeObject data (class: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon)
```

If I remove the list from FlightExt then everything works fine, which indicates there is no problem with the lambda function serialization.

Scala on its own seems to serialize a list of Int's fine. Perhaps Spark has an issue with serializing Lists?

I've also tried using a Java Integer.

EDIT:

If I change List to Array it works but if I have something like this:

```
case class FlightExt(callsign: Option[String], other: Array[AnotherCaseClass])
```

It also fails with the same error

I'm new to Scala and Spark and may be missing something, but any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Turns out that Spark 1.6 does not support serialization of lists.

Answer (score 0):

Put `FlightExt` class inside `object`, Check below code.

```
object Flight {
 case class FlightExt(callsign: Option[String], var serials: List[Int])
}
```

Use `Flight.FlightExt`

```
val (ctx, sctx) = SparkUtil.createContext() // just a helper function to build context
    val flightsDataFrame = separateFlightsMock(sctx) // reads data from Parquet file

    import sctx.implicits._
    flightsDataFrame.as[Flight.FlightExt]
      .map(flight => flight.callsign)
      .show()
```

Comment: Thanks, only now I get: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unable to generate an encoder for inner class `org.some.package.Flight$FlightExt` without access to the scope that this class was defined in. Try moving this class out of its parent class. Do I need a custom encoder or something for that now?